# Django - can't update model in database

Tags: python, django

I have a table in my database (`postgresql`) that is associated with a `model` called `feedback` in my Django app (which is also called `feedback`).

I deleted a couple of columns of the `feedback` model in the `models.py` file and then created a migration using:

```
python manage.py makemigrations feedback
```

And then tried to "merge" it with my database using:

```
python manage.py migrate feedback
```

But i got the error:
`django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "feedback" already exists`

Of course it exists, but i want to apply the changes i've made. In the `migrations` folder i have the following files:

```
__init__.py
0001_initial.py
0002_remove_feedback_created_on.py
0003_remove_feedback_is_read.py
```

The last one contains my most recent changes. What should i do?

Comment: Did the previous migrations by any chance went wrong?

Comment: Yes, `0002` was never applied, i got the same error. I tried deleting `0002` and `0003` (since `0001` was ok) and now i'm left with the changes i've made as `0002` but i still get the same error when i try to migrate that `0002`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this `relation x already exists` problem appears when you've applied the change at some point in the database, but the Django migrations system hasn't got a clue about the fact that you already did that. How could it happen? For example if you add a `ForeignKey` field to your model, make a migration, migrate it, but then change your mind and delete the migration without migrating backwards before that. Nothing breaks in the project, but the relationship and the field in the database remain (you might run into trouble, if the field is non-nullable). Now if you change your mind again and decide that shiiit, I needed that field anyhows and add it again, make a new migration and try to migrate it, then you get the `relation x already exists` error.

Ok, what then? Usually the simplest way is to fake the failing migration, but **BEWARE** that if you have any other unapplied changes in the migrations, then those won't be applied to the database either. Before you start faking migrations, make sure that you understand what and why you are faking. Ideally you'd have only one `AddField` in the migration file that is soon to be faked, because otherwise all changes in the migration file will be faked (faking migrations means, that the changes are not applied to database, but Django will consider them done).

If you have two unapplied migrations, then you definitely shouldn't run `migrate --fake` without specifying the migration number, because then the latter unapplied migration will be unapplied as well. It SEEMS in your case, that running `manage.py migrate 0002 --fake` and `manage.py migrate` afterwards might fix everything, but without knowing everything about what you've done, it's impossible to say for certain.

If I picked up your project, here's what I would do:
1) Check if `0002` contains more than one change.
If yes, then copy everything except the failing field to `0003`.
If no, then proceed to `manage.py migrate 0002 --fake`.
2) Run `manage.py migrate` again to migrate `0003`.

Answer (score 0):

It could also help in the case of migrations.

python3 manage.py migrate --run-syncdb